# Different size thumbnail to custom category

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, categories

I want to set in index different size thumbnail to custom category. But how to do that if post have two or more category?

Comment: show some code . what did you try . what do you want to achieve

Comment: `if(is_category( array( 4, 'category-slug', 'My category' ))) :
    $my_thumbnail = 'thumbnailsize1';
   else:
    $my_thumbnail = 'thumbnailsize2';
   endif;`

Answer (score 0):

you will want to add a image size (set_post_thumbnail_size) for posts (or custom posts) and then you will want to use it. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you might get away with having a different page to render a list of posts with that category.  check out:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

Answer (score 0):

```
 function pr_setup() {

        add_image_size( 'thumb1', 132, 64 ); // 132 is width , 64 is height 

        add_image_size( 'thumb2',400, 300);

    }

    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'pr_setup' );

    if(is_category( array( 4, 'category-slug', 'My category' ))) :

      $my_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail('thumb1'); 
   else:
      $my_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail('thumb2'); 
    endif;
```

Learn more about add_image_size on codex !

Comment: Image size had already been added, do not know how to change depending on the category.

Answer (score 0):

I have just finished, I did something like this:

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID('My category');
    if ( in_category($category_id) ) :
        $thumb = 'thumbnailsize1';
    else :
        $thumb = 'thumbnailsize2';
    endif;
```

I think it works :)